# undefined reference when cross-compiling for ARM with static OpenCV libraries

Tags: linux, opencv, static, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a simple test program using static OpenCV libraries that have been compiled using an ARM compiler. But when I try to compile it with the command

```
$arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ `pkg-config --static opencv` -I/usr/local/include -L<path to static libary>  -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core ARMtest2.cpp -o ARMtest2
```

This gives

> /tmp/ccxNeUbK.o: In function `main':
>   ARMtest2.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to`cv::Mat::ones(int, int, int)'
>   /tmp/ccxNeUbK.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
>   ARMtest2.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to`cv::fastFree(void*)'
>   /tmp/ccxNeUbK.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
>   ARMtest2.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x30): undefined reference to`cv::Mat::deallocate()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The code itself is just some simple test code that prints a Mat type variable.

I compiled the static OpenCV library with cmake-gui. I selected UNIX Makefile and then selected 'specify options for cross-compiling' where I gave the path to the ARM (arm-linux-gnueabihf) gcc and g++ compiler. Then I unticked BUILD_SHARED_LIB so it compiled static libraries. It seemed to compile fine without errors. After that I did make & sudo make install.

I also tried it with shared libraries and that worked fine on the ARM board (once I copied the libraries to the board and exported the library path).

The static .a files landed nicely in the build folder. Apparently it can also find it when I -L link to it. I have tried reversing the order of the libraries, but to no avail.

So I'm a bit at a loss what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Using the normal --static pkg-config command to compile with OpenCV libraries;

```
 `pkg-config --libs --static opencv`
```

Of course I installed the static libraries also to the folder /usr/local/lib where libraries get installed first. But still i don't know what I missed in the command line I tried to use. I had a look in the config file /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

Here is whats in it:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.9
Libs:  ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_contrib.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_core.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_features2d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_flann.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_gpu.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_highgui.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_legacy.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ml.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ocl.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_photo.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_stitching.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_superres.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ts.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_video.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_videostab.so -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

I believe this is what is being called with the `pkg-config <--something_or_other> opencv` line.
And saw some other things that probably get linked when compiling `-lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl` Not really sure though as I tried it ina normal command line and I apparently still missed somethings.
But it worked, so didn't really bother too much with it much further :)

Answer (score 0):

In your command:

```
*$arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ `pkg-config --static opencv` -I/usr/local/include -L<path to static libary>  -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core ARMtest2.cpp -o ARMtest2*
```

The cflags was missing.

Try with:

```
$arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ `pkg-config --cflags --static opencv` -I/usr/local/include -L<path to static cross-compiled libary> -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core ARMtest2.cpp -o ARMtest2
```

Assuming here that your cross-compiled headers are saved in /usr/local/include (as you specified).